# search inside arrays with condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, fetch-api, array-key

I have an api with a list of arrays inside one array and each array inside this array it has one key [attributes] and inside this key one array with key [CITY_NAME]

this is my array coming from api
this array number is 0 but every day this number is changed and my figures come wrong, what is the good way to always have my city figures using the key [CITY_NAME]

I am fetching the data using this code

```html
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = $json_data['features'];
$mycity = $data[0]['attributes'];
```

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [CITY_NAME] => city1
                    [Name] => city1
                    [ADMIN_NAME] => city1
                    [POP_CLASS] => 5,000,000 to10,000,000
                    [Population] => 7676654
                    [Population_Data_Source] => Wikipedia
                    [Population_Data_Date] => 2018
                    [CityID] => 14
                    [Longitude] => 46.7614868685786
                    [Latitude] => 24.7388786516234
                    [Confirmed] => 0
                    [Recovered] => 0
                    [Deaths] => 0
                    [Active] => 0
                    [Tested] => 0
                    [Name_Eng] => city1
                    [Join_Count] => 61
                    [Confirmed_SUM] => 5152
                    [Deaths_SUM] => 9
                    [Recovered_SUM] => 1407
                    [Active_SUM] => 3736
                    [Tested_SUM] => 376607
                    [ObjectId] => 14
                )

        )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [CITY_NAME] => city2
                [Name] => city2
                [ADMIN_NAME] => city2
                [POP_CLASS] => 1,000,000 to 5,000,000
                [Population] => 1675368
                [Population_Data_Source] => Wikipedia
                [Population_Data_Date] => 2010
                [CityID] => 9
                [Longitude] => 39.8148987363852
                [Latitude] => 21.4273876500039
                [Confirmed] => 0
                [Recovered] => 0
                [Deaths] => 0
                [Active] => 0
                [Tested] => 0
                [Name_Eng] => city2
                [Join_Count] => 59
                [Confirmed_SUM] => 6848
                [Deaths_SUM] => 85
                [Recovered_SUM] => 1145
                [Active_SUM] => 5618
                [Tested_SUM] => 0
                [ObjectId] => 9
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I may have misunderstood and you may have many, just build a new array with `CITY_NAME`:

```
foreach($data as $values) {
    $result[$values['attributes']['CITY_NAME']] = $values['attributes'];
}
```

Now you can access by `CITY_NAME`:

```
echo $result['city1']['Population'];
```

This might be easier.  Extract all `attributes` from all arrays into an array, then create an array from that indexed by `CITY_NAME`:

```
$data = array_column(array_column($json_data['features'], 'attributes'), 
                     null, 'CITY_NAME');
```

Comment: thanks @AbrCadaver actually there is a lot but I posted only one as example

Comment: There is a lot but you only want the first?  If not, then how do you know which ones you want?  You aren't showing a loop.

Comment: using this key [CITY_NAME] => city1, each array has this key and suppose my city name is city1, how can search for this city inside this arrays?

Comment: Edited to hopefully get something usable.

Comment: Thanks this is works perfectly, but if the array number is changed, this is won't change right?